# Question about the following notation (groups and homomorphism)

Tags: group-theory, notation, cryptography, group-homomorphism

So I was reading a paper on homomorphic encryption, and it in turn introduces some concepts that I didn't know much about before (primarily groups).

I have a few questions but I'll first post the pertinent paragraph in the paper:

> "Earlier, homomorphic encryption was defined as a form of encryption
>   where a specific algebraic operation performed on plaintext is
>   equivalent to another algebraic operation performed on its ciphertext.
>   In mathematics, these operations are called mappings or functions and
>   are operation preserving (OP) mappings. For example, if *(G,o)* and
>   *(H,$^*$)*  represent groups, an OP mapping h:*(G,o)* $\to \!\,$ *(H,$^*$)* is called a homomorphism from  *(G,o)* to *(H,$^*$)*. The groups  *(G,o)* and *(H,$^*$)*  represent sets of data and the mapping
>   (function) that maps the set *(G,o)* onto or into the set *(H,$^*$)*
>   is *h*. This function is an operation that preserves the structure
>   from one set of data to the other set of data.
>
> ....
>
> To further explain how homomorphism works, we consider two sets of
>   data. One is the set of positive real numbers, *R$^+$*, and the other
>   set is the logarithms of this set of real numbers. On these sets, the
>   multiplication of real numbers and the addition of logarithms and
>   homomorphic operations. If we consider any real positive numbers *x,
>   y, z, if x × y = z, then log(x) + log(y) = log(z).* "

So my questions are as follows:

Using the notation from the first paragraph, would it be mathematically correct to write the following:

The operational preserving mapping h: (R$^+$, ×) $\to \!\,$ (L, +) (where I define L to be the set of logarithms of the positive real numbers) is called a homomorphism from (R$^+$, ×) to (L, +) (assuming (L,+) is a group).

Furthermore, if the function h represented an encryption function (that I'll call e), and M my set of plaintext messages and C my set of ciphertexts, could I say the following?

My encryption function will be called e

e: (M,o) $\to \!\,$ (C,*) is a group homomorphism from (M,o) to (C,$^*$), and would the reverse automatically be true?

Meaning  is

d: (C,*) $\to \!\,$ (M,o) a group homomorphism from (M,o) to (C,$^*$), where d is my decryption function and o and $^*$ are operations on the sets M and C respectively?

Comment: If $e$ is a homomorphism and a bijection (so that its inverse $d$ exists) then $d$ is automatically a homomorphism.

Comment: And what's more that's not hard to prove, just using the defintions of "group", "homomorphism", "bijection".